# Grails controlling command prompt

Tags: grails, inno-setup, command-prompt

I have a project in grails I made and I also have an install packager (inno-setup) that I am using to distribute installs of some software.  I use a portal i made generate a config file that the installer uses to package the software needed.  However I am trying to get my portal (which is made in grails) to feed the install packager the script and generate the file.  Right now I have to do it myself in Command Prompt.  Is there any way to have grails open command prompt, type in what I need to generate the install, execute, and then close command prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [java.lang.Runtime.exec(String command)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29%20%22java.lang.Runtime.exec%28String%20command%29) to execute a shell script from Java.